# Converting a string to a long via ASCII conversion

Tags: java

As the title suggestions, Im trying to convert a string into a unique long by converting each char to ascii.

```
 public class MyClass {
    public long AsciiFromString(String inString)

        String tempString = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < inString.length(); i++) {
                char c = inString.charAt(i);
                String charAsASCIIString = Integer.toString((int) c);
                tempString = tempString + charAsASCIIString;

            }
            return Long.parseLong(tempString);
        }
```

This method throws a number format error when I pass in a string

Comment: missing a `{` after `public long AsciiFromString(String inString)`. And missing `catch` block after the `try` block

Comment: Sorry about the try block , i actually have a try catch but removed it (obvs not all the way) to make it easier to read.  ill clean it up

Comment: This is a really bad idea! If your string has many characters, `Long` won't  be able to hold that value.

Comment: Im going to check out BigInt as suggested below

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine. But if the computed string is `> Long.MAX_VALUE` you will get a number format exception. You also need a catch block with your try block.

```
long v = AsciiFromString("thisisa");
System.out.println(v);
```

prints

```
116104105115105115
```

Your method

```
    
public static long AsciiFromString(String inString) {
    
    String tempString = "";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < inString.length(); i++) {
        char c = inString.charAt(i);
        String charAsASCIIString = Integer.toString((int) c);
        tempString = tempString + charAsASCIIString;
        
    }
    return Long.parseLong(tempString);
}
```

Comment: My input string can be up to 35 char 0-9 a-z A-Z.  so a long cant hold that?

Comment: No it can't.   Look at my answer and see the test string and the resulting value.  For those types of computations, check out the `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal` classes which support math operations on arbitrary length numbers.

Comment: got it.  Ill see what BigInt give me

Comment: @TheUltimateHack when you say, “My input string can be up to 35 char 0-9 a-z A-Z”, I’m wondering whether you’re describing the wrong operation. Are you actually describing the base₃₆ system, where the digits 0-9 and the letters a-z make up 36 digits? That can be parsed using `Long.parseLong(inString, 36)`.

Comment: @Holger  You know I never questioned why the OP wanted to do it, but you raise a good point.  I hadn't considered radix conversion.

Comment: I usually do both, answer the literal question, but also address the striking issues. Here, I noticed that `char c = inString.charAt(i); String charAsASCIIString = Integer.toString((int) c); tempString = tempString + charAsASCIIString;` is a long winded way to say `tempString += (int)inString.charAt(i);` but letting the inefficiency of repeated string concatenation aside, concatenating decimal numbers wouldn’t even create unique string if the OP didn’t say that only 0-9 and a-z can occur. In the end, the task is a but underspecified and the code not sufficient to derive the task from it.